# Convert Ajax Callback Data to JQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code is doing an AJAX call that returns one or more `<li>` elements in a simple string... the function needs to return a JQuery object.  I want to be able to loop through each `<li>` element in the data string by treating the string data as a JQuery object.  How can I convert this simple string into a valid JQuery object?

the ondata function's data parameter contains simple string content looking like this:

```
<li title="ID: 2" id="abc" rel="departmentgroup" class="closed"><a href="#" class="xxx" ><ins class="departmentgroup">&nbsp;</ins>Hierarchy(8)</a></li> <li title="ID: 3" id="def" rel="departmentgroup" class="closed"><a href="#" class="xxx" ><ins class="departmentgroup">&nbsp;</ins>Floating(62)</a></li>
```

in the code you see below, I'm attempting to .clone() this data but that statement errors because data isn't a JQuery object... I need it to be.

```
ondata: function(data, tree){
newData = $(data).clone();
        $.each($(newData).find("a"), function(i, item){
    if ($('#' +  $(item).attr("rel") + '-Path').length > 0) {
        $(item).children('ins').attr("connected", "true");
        $(item).children('ins').attr("class", "tick");
    }
    $("#relational-tree").data('loaded', 'true');
    });
return $(newData);
}
```

Comment: this should work, if you test this "$('<li>sfsdfsdf</li>').clone()", it works fine. Can you share the string you are receiving in 'data' variable? ... tried this also $('<li title="ID: 2" id="abc" rel="departmentgroup" class="closed"><a href="#" class="xxx" ><ins class="departmentgroup">&nbsp;</ins>Hierarchy(8)</a></li> <li title="ID: 3" id="def" rel="departmentgroup" class="closed"><a href="#" class="xxx" ><ins class="departmentgroup">&nbsp;</ins>Floating(62)</a></li>').clone() , it works fine.

Comment: @HamidRaza Well, I've shared it above... and you've used it in your example... I guess I'm just trying to figure out the proper way to reference the data variable.  my code's statement newData = $(data).clone(); causes jquery.js to throw an "unrecognized expression" error where the contents of the data variable are listed as the syntax error.  newData = data.clone(); returns the error "data.clone() is not a function"

Comment: Try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/XaqV3/ ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(data) does return a jquery object. Not sure why you are cloning it... here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/parit/n2t2X/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var a = $('<li title="ID: 2" id="abc" rel="departmentgroup" class="closed"><a href="#" class="xxx" >Hierarchy(8)</a></li><li title="ID: 3" id="def" rel="departmentgroup" class="closed"><a href="#" class="xxx" >Floating(62)</a></li>')
$.each(a, function (index, element) {
    alert($(element).attr('title'))
})
```

});